# Get-ChildItem - Slow

Tags: powershell-4.0, processing-efficiency, get-childitem

Running Powershell V4.0. Below is script to search through 1000's of files by date stamp in filename in given date range and find all matching strings. However Get-ChildItem cmdlet is extremely slow. I'm new to Powershell. Any way to make this more efficient? Perhaps read in batches?

```
######################################################
#Date ranges and filename
$startdate = [datetime]'01/26/2017'
$enddate = [datetime] '02/05/2017'
$Filename = "DACNBA0124IDT030"
######################################################
#Progress

######################################################


$array = 
do {
   $startdate.ToString('yyyy_MM_dd*')
   $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
  }

until ($startdate -gt [datetime] $enddate)

$files = $array | foreach-object {"G:\Live Engineering\AsRuns\Test\$_*"}

write-host $files

$Matches = get-childitem $files -recurse -force -OutBuffer 20000 | select-  string $Filename | Where -Verbose {$_.line -notlike '*.mxf'}
$Matches.Matches.Count > "C:\Users\user\Desktop\report app\Log.txt"
```

Comment: Specify the pattern to look for directly select-string or `-exclude *.mxf` files directly in get-child-item. Anyway it'd be good to see an example of the files you process, their size, whether it's a network drive.

Comment: To search reasonably quickly through hundreds of thousands of files on network-attached storage, I had to switch to `cmd /c dir /b /s ...`. It was an order of magnitude faster on my network.

Answer (score 0):

I have a helper function which I use it everyday at my work. I have the available in my GitHub repo.

I have two cmdlets in it which does the same and more...

hope will help you .

https://github.com/kvprasoon/PSReadScript

Feel free to post issues/Bugs and request there

regards,

Kvprasoon